# EntityFramework context doesn't retrieve any data when created in a different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Fellow coders,

I am facing a weird issue using Entity Framework and I would like to understand what the root cause of this :

I have a shared project (**Project A**) across a solution which contains my data model class Foo.cs.

This data model is used into another asp core project (**Project B**), and tied to a database via an application specific context. I updated databases using "Code First" approach.

I can perform Database manipulations from **Project B** without any trouble (load data, retrieve them, and so on).

But, now, I'd like to perform manipulations from **Project A** as well. So, i naively created a new DbContext into this project (I cannot reference the one from ***Project B***, there is already a reference from A to B), but when trying to load data, I get empty records, despite it's connecting well to the Database.

```
public class ProjectADbContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectADbContext (string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}


public class GetDatas
{
    private static void GetDatas()
    {
        using (ProjectADbContext context = new ProjectADbContext (Configuration.RemoteDBConnectionString))
        {
            context.Foos.Load(); //Get an empty record list
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Does EF think it is not the same data type between the two contexts?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Few months later, and as discussed in comments, It looks like the issue was coming from the fact that **one project was a .NET Standard project whereas the other one was running on .NET Core, with two different EFs**.

Migrating the Project A to .NET Core solved the issue.

This answer is half satisfactory since I don't understand the root cause of it but it may help someone troubleshooting with the same configuration.

Comment: Are you sure the passed Connection string is correct? the Configuration class should be project dependent, therefore they may be different. data type mismatches cannot be the case, as EF just does property matching when converting the result set; so either its configuration is different so it is looking at another table, in another schema, or a whole different database.

Comment: Have you installed the EntityFrameworkCore nuget package in ProjectA?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro yes the connection string is correct; actually it connects well to the DB. What do you mean by "EF is looking at a different table or in a different schema"? How is the table chosen? Since both contexts refer to the same underlying model, it should be the same table don't you think? And there is only one DB.

Comment: @LawrenceZahner Actually one project runs on .NET Standard and the other one on .NET Core. Do you think it can lead to an issue?